# Clearing table in database when exit from webpage

Tags: php, sql

Is there a way to clear a database when you close certain php file? Such that when the user closes a web page, the table in a database gets cleared/empty. It is such as cookies are deleted when you close a webpage, so the user also wants to clear the database when he exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use "beforeunload" event in JavaScript to call an AJAX request that will tell your server to clear the data:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e){
   // Call your script here
}, false);
```

However, this (as any other user input) is very unreliable, for an example, if JavaScript is disabled, browser tab closes not the way it is expected (killed process, forcibly rebooted PC, etc.).